# Trying to draw ARGB data of unsigned long to HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an array of unsigned_long ARGB data. So this data here is 16 x 16 image so its 16^2 elements = 256.

I'm not able to draw it to data, `ctx.createImageData(theData)` is throwing `Exception: TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData does not implement interface ImageData.`

Here is my code:

```
function drawARGBData(theData) {
    //theData is an array of size width x height
    //must be square image, so like 16 by 16

    var doc = document;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = Math.pow(theData.length, 0.5);
    canvas.height = Math.pow(theData.length, 0.5);

    ctx.createImageData(theData);

}

    var argbData_16by16 = [
        '16777215',
        '50331648',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '117440512',
        '50331648',
        '16777215',
        '117440512',
        '18446744073529823931',
        '18446744073695757494',
        '18446744073702049907',
        '18446744073706972004',
        '18446744073697459863',
        '18446744073697861829',
        '18446744073700887771',
        '18446744073700821978',
        '18446744073696939192',
        '18446744073697191287',
        '18446744073704609876',
        '18446744073708880971',
        '18446744073709208895',
        '18446744073603027557',
        '117440512',
        '520093696',
        '18446744073707627114',
        '18446744073706307642',
        '18446744073707882278',
        '18446744073700534358',
        '18446744073693656498',
        '18446744073696154558',
        '18446744073699509204',
        '18446744073699509204',
        '18446744073695560369',
        '18446744073693387160',
        '18446744073693253257',
        '18446744073699420739',
        '18446744073708951059',
        '18446744073709414460',
        '520093696',
        '587202560',
        '18446744073707551525',
        '18446744073707352597',
        '18446744073707352592',
        '18446744073700988478',
        '18446744073693586584',
        '18446744073697795765',
        '18446744073699442897',
        '18446744073699508947',
        '18446744073695954868',
        '18446744073693386904',
        '18446744073693648790',
        '18446744073693318539',
        '18446744073696857935',
        '18446744073708881935',
        '587202560',
        '587202560',
        '18446744073707485220',
        '18446744073707418395',
        '18446744073706891281',
        '18446744073706425097',
        '18446744073707345161',
        '18446744073704531761',
        '18446744073699046598',
        '18446744073698324168',
        '18446744073696546743',
        '18446744073696545716',
        '18446744073698915275',
        '18446744073697992127',
        '18446744073693117300',
        '18446744073705326624',
        '587202560',
        '654311424',
        '18446744073707484962',
        '18446744073707418395',
        '18446744073707418395',
        '18446744073707885140',
        '18446744073708550015',
        '18446744073701858961',
        '18446744073699244237',
        '18446744073697994179',
        '18446744073698783690',
        '18446744073698914762',
        '18446744073696807346',
        '18446744073698122943',
        '18446744073694828680',
        '18446744073706314294',
        '654311424',
        '654311424',
        '18446744073707484961',
        '18446744073707418395',
        '18446744073707484959',
        '18446744073707227449',
        '18446744073698777775',
        '18446744073698979529',
        '18446744073699045578',
        '18446744073699045578',
        '18446744073698650566',
        '18446744073693646990',
        '18446744073693712013',
        '18446744073695224729',
        '18446744073697987759',
        '18446744073708161575',
        '654311424',
        '687865856',
        '18446744073707418911',
        '18446744073706628121',
        '18446744073706041131',
        '18446744073705459278',
        '18446744073698054320',
        '18446744073698714307',
        '18446744073698780612',
        '18446744073698780612',
        '18446744073698714563',
        '18446744073696014754',
        '18446744073693117053',
        '18446744073693576313',
        '18446744073695482750',
        '18446744073708749070',
        '687865856',
        '704643072',
        '18446744073703796493',
        '18446744073703464706',
        '18446744073700791369',
        '18446744073697854638',
        '18446744073697987762',
        '18446744073698317499',
        '18446744073698383548',
        '18446744073698383548',
        '18446744073698317756',
        '18446744073697066154',
        '18446744073693048947',
        '18446744073692981351',
        '18446744073701911603',
        '18446744073709003020',
        '704643072',
        '721420288',
        '18446744073704451076',
        '18446744073705305601',
        '18446744073706038045',
        '18446744073698827363',
        '18446744073697388940',
        '18446744073698830196',
        '18446744073702503249',
        '18446744073700997739',
        '18446744073697590183',
        '18446744073696799906',
        '18446744073693507184',
        '18446744073692912989',
        '18446744073707961160',
        '18446744073709070346',
        '721420288',
        '754974720',
        '18446744073706424325',
        '18446744073707277312',
        '18446744073707348239',
        '18446744073707418395',
        '18446744073707418395',
        '18446744073707418395',
        '18446744073707287325',
        '18446744073707295294',
        '18446744073698368621',
        '18446744073692912481',
        '18446744073692780636',
        '18446744073693238859',
        '18446744073708885589',
        '18446744073709137681',
        '754974720',
        '771751936',
        '18446744073707482647',
        '18446744073707544331',
        '18446744073707413517',
        '18446744073703663880',
        '18446744073704059402',
        '18446744073704654868',
        '18446744073702755885',
        '18446744073696790647',
        '18446744073694951036',
        '18446744073692779609',
        '18446744073695995961',
        '18446744073703812899',
        '18446744073709282817',
        '18446744073709072423',
        '771751936',
        '805306368',
        '18446744073707418650',
        '18446744073707352597',
        '18446744073707417624',
        '18446744073706301726',
        '18446744073698554672',
        '18446744073693238865',
        '18446744073695671171',
        '18446744073693831018',
        '18446744073695670659',
        '18446744073696980549',
        '18446744073706696221',
        '18446744073708214284',
        '18446744073708615680',
        '18446744073709277532',
        '805306368',
        '822083584',
        '18446744073707485212',
        '18446744073707352592',
        '18446744073707418390',
        '18446744073707352595',
        '18446744073707418393',
        '18446744073704332580',
        '18446744073699801657',
        '18446744073700326456',
        '18446744073702165039',
        '18446744073706892829',
        '18446744073707418650',
        '18446744073707881733',
        '18446744073708679704',
        '18446744073709417314',
        '822083584',
        '520093696',
        '18446744073603404600',
        '18446744073706757147',
        '18446744073707353372',
        '18446744073707485472',
        '18446744073707485468',
        '18446744073707617831',
        '18446744073707684400',
        '18446744073707684401',
        '18446744073707617837',
        '18446744073707551527',
        '18446744073707415827',
        '18446744073707949578',
        '18446744073709418781',
        '18446744073604998444',
        '520093696',
        '50331648',
        '822083584',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '1493172224',
        '822083584',
        '50331648'
    ];

    drawARGBData(argbData_16by16);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mask and shift

Simple shift operation to extract the values as r, g and b - for each value entry:

```
// assumes big-endian byte-order for ARGB
var uint32 = argbData_16by16[i],   // i represents the iterator
    r = (uint32 & 0xff0000)>>>16;
    g = (uint32 & 0xff00)>>>8,
    b = uint32 & 0xff,
    a = (uint32 & 0xff000000)>>>24;
```

```js
function drawARGBData(theData) {
    //theData is an array of size width x height
    //must be square image, so like 16 by 16

    var doc = document;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 16;
    canvas.height = 16;

    var idata = ctx.createImageData(16, 16);
    for(var i = 0, t = 0; i < theData.length; i++) {
      var uint32 = +theData[i]; // convert to number right away (source is string here)
      idata.data[t++] = (uint32 & 0xff0000)>>>16;
      idata.data[t++] = (uint32 & 0xff00)>>>8;
      idata.data[t++] = uint32 & 0xff;;
      idata.data[t++] = (uint32 & 0xff000000)>>>24;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
}

var argb_16x16_LONG = [
 '16777215',
 '50331648',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '117440512',
 '50331648',
 '16777215',
 '117440512',
 '-179727685',
 '-13794122',
 '-7501709',
 '-2579612',
 '-12091753',
 '-11689787',
 '-8663845',
 '-8729638',
 '-12612424',
 '-12360329',
 '-4941740',
 '-670645',
 '-342721',
 '-106524059',
 '117440512',
 '520093696',
 '-1924502',
 '-3243974',
 '-1669338',
 '-9017258',
 '-15895118',
 '-13397058',
 '-10042412',
 '-10042412',
 '-13991247',
 '-16164456',
 '-16298359',
 '-10130877',
 '-600557',
 '-137156',
 '520093696',
 '587202560',
 '-2000091',
 '-2199019',
 '-2199024',
 '-8563138',
 '-15965032',
 '-11755851',
 '-10108719',
 '-10042669',
 '-13596748',
 '-16164712',
 '-15902826',
 '-16233077',
 '-12693681',
 '-669681',
 '587202560',
 '587202560',
 '-2066396',
 '-2133221',
 '-2660335',
 '-3126519',
 '-2206455',
 '-5019855',
 '-10505018',
 '-11227448',
 '-13004873',
 '-13005900',
 '-10636341',
 '-11559489',
 '-16434316',
 '-4224992',
 '587202560',
 '654311424',
 '-2066654',
 '-2133221',
 '-2133221',
 '-1666476',
 '-1001601',
 '-7692655',
 '-10307379',
 '-11557437',
 '-10767926',
 '-10636854',
 '-12744270',
 '-11428673',
 '-14722936',
 '-3237322',
 '654311424',
 '654311424',
 '-2066655',
 '-2133221',
 '-2066657',
 '-2324167',
 '-10773841',
 '-10572087',
 '-10506038',
 '-10506038',
 '-10901050',
 '-15904626',
 '-15839603',
 '-14326887',
 '-11563857',
 '-1390041',
 '654311424',
 '687865856',
 '-2132705',
 '-2923495',
 '-3510485',
 '-4092338',
 '-11497296',
 '-10837309',
 '-10771004',
 '-10771004',
 '-10837053',
 '-13536862',
 '-16434563',
 '-15975303',
 '-14068866',
 '-802546',
 '687865856',
 '704643072',
 '-5755123',
 '-6086910',
 '-8760247',
 '-11696978',
 '-11563854',
 '-11234117',
 '-11168068',
 '-11168068',
 '-11233860',
 '-12485462',
 '-16502669',
 '-16570265',
 '-7640013',
 '-548596',
 '704643072',
 '721420288',
 '-5100540',
 '-4246015',
 '-3513571',
 '-10724253',
 '-12162676',
 '-10721420',
 '-7048367',
 '-8553877',
 '-11961433',
 '-12751710',
 '-16044432',
 '-16638627',
 '-1590456',
 '-481270',
 '721420288',
 '754974720',
 '-3127291',
 '-2274304',
 '-2203377',
 '-2133221',
 '-2133221',
 '-2133221',
 '-2264291',
 '-2256322',
 '-11182995',
 '-16639135',
 '-16770980',
 '-16312757',
 '-666027',
 '-413935',
 '754974720',
 '771751936',
 '-2068969',
 '-2007285',
 '-2138099',
 '-5887736',
 '-5492214',
 '-4896748',
 '-6795731',
 '-12760969',
 '-14600580',
 '-16772007',
 '-13555655',
 '-5738717',
 '-268799',
 '-479193',
 '771751936',
 '805306368',
 '-2132966',
 '-2199019',
 '-2133992',
 '-3249890',
 '-10996944',
 '-16312751',
 '-13880445',
 '-15720598',
 '-13880957',
 '-12571067',
 '-2855395',
 '-1337332',
 '-935936',
 '-274084',
 '805306368',
 '822083584',
 '-2066404',
 '-2199024',
 '-2133226',
 '-2199021',
 '-2133223',
 '-5219036',
 '-9749959',
 '-9225160',
 '-7386577',
 '-2658787',
 '-2132966',
 '-1669883',
 '-871912',
 '-134302',
 '822083584',
 '520093696',
 '-106147016',
 '-2794469',
 '-2198244',
 '-2066144',
 '-2066148',
 '-1933785',
 '-1867216',
 '-1867215',
 '-1933779',
 '-2000089',
 '-2135789',
 '-1602038',
 '-132835',
 '-104553172',
 '520093696',
 '50331648',
 '822083584',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '1493172224',
 '822083584',
 '50331648'
];
drawARGBData(argb_16x16_LONG);
```

Comment: Thanks Ken! Yes these are actually `UInt64` numbers I'm trying to get into JS.

Comment: I got the image as LONG: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/7d4e32cde6179b600331 but we have negative numbers in there now, would that be ok?

Comment: @Noitidart they will be converted to unsigned (it will treat the sign bit as a regular bit). You can see this in console: `(-1>>>0).toString(16)` or just `-1>>>0`. This will end up with 0xffffffff `var a = new Uint32Array([-1])`

Comment: Hi there Ken, I got a dump of what the goal is. The first array here is what the rgba values should be: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/e12b84171480823e3d97 then the second and thrid arrays are the `long` and `unsigned long` datas. The rgba output by the method 2 above are not matching them :( so the pics are coming out differnetly colored. This is what method 2 outputs for rgba: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/fd914bed098f59b0105c and this is a pic of the actual pic drawn and then the argb drawn: can you please advise :( forgive the bother you you already helped so much!

Comment: Oops forgot to post the image here it is: http://i.imgur.com/dhv1IWP.png :) Maybe it has something to do with dataview? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921424/dataview-converting-1px-by-1px-rgba-to-argb

Comment: Oh wheni got the long and ulong data they said its a ARGB data I got it with C functions of X11 Unix of `XGetWindowProperty` on `_NET_WM_ICON`: http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472644112

Comment: Absolutely soooo coool! Thank you so much for this spoon feed I promise I'll learn from it. I'm trying to learn DataView right now so I can handle the endian'ness. This helps a ton! I was curious though is not possible to back out the alpha from this?

Comment: @Noitidart seem as I was the one mistaken. I updated it to convert alpha channel, but the color order is then ARGB as you stated frst... (I also assumed it read ABGR but see now it's ARGB, canvas is RGBA). sorry, it's been a long day :) Now things are correct.

Comment: Noooo sorry's please thank you verry veryy much!! I'm going to try do this with DataView too to learn it! Thank you!! :)

Comment: Forgive this bother again i was trying to learn dataViews so tried your first method but it keeps drawing a blank :( https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/2e2e3dbf50a097797c6b

Comment: @Noitidart yeah, I removed it since the byte order wouldn't be correct for it (needs RGBA, but data is ARGB so they need conversion at byte level anyways). Also, I forgot to include a Uint8Array conversion when setting: `idata.data.set(new Uint8Array(uint32array.buffer));` See http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/8uxk60by/ but as said, since the order is ARGB you will have to use the method left in the answer.

Comment: Ah superb thank you. yep its not right color but i learned a lot from that comment and fiddel about that will help me to learn DataView and TypedArrays !:)

Answer (score 1):

`theData` needs to be an [ImageData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) which is created like this: `new ImageData(array,width,height)` where “width” and “height” are both 16 in your case but “array” is the typed array `Uint8ClampedArray`.

This ImageData object *implements the ImageData interface* as required and mentioned by the exception message.

A [Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) is an array of numbers ranging from 0 to 255. To be used with ImageData you have to have that array filled with 1024 (16 × 16 × 4) of such numbers—4 for R, G, B, A.

Constructing the ImageData object and creating the image data would look something like this:

```
var image_data_object = new ImageData(
  new Uint8ClampedArray([
    /* Red, Green, Blue, Alpha, repeating in that order, pixel by pixel. */
    r_0,g_0,b_0,a_0,
    r_1,g_1,b_1,a_1,
    255,0,0,255, // represents red
    102,51,153,127, // represents semitransparent rebeccapurple
    /* etc. */
    r_n,g_n,b_n,a_n
  ]),
  16,
  16);
```

Then the function call:

```
drawARGBData(image_data_object);
```

**Note: It’s not ARGB, but RGBA here.**

To actually draw the image data onto the canvas you can use `ctx.putImageData(theData,0,0)`.

Also: this is new for me as well. I recommend visiting the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for such things where I just got to know about all that for myself.

Comment: Thanks Xufox I was using that MDN page but getting stuck.